# FileUpload handler to enable submit button

Tags: forms, gwt, file-upload, filter

I work with GWT and I have a FileUpload widget and a submit Button in a Form. The expected behaviour is:
- When a file is attached, submit button is enabled.
- When the file is dettached, submit button is disabled again.
- Only .JS files will be visible during the FileUpload browsing.

Which handlers/functions should I use for these purposes?

THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try registering a`ChangeHandler`:

```
fileUpload.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler{
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {

        // filename of selected file
        String fileName = fileUpload.getFilename();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And to show only .JS files while browsing the FileUpload? Is it possible?

Comment: This is not supported by most browsers, so GWT can not implement it. There is the input tag accept attrtibute: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select#Accept_attribute, but it seem that it only works on Opera and Chrome.

Comment: Also see this [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/82b725c6ec44e391?pli=1) on GWT list